# Is it possible to download a existing smart contract state from a blockchain and deploying it in a different blockchain?

Tags: contract-deployment, state-trie

Suppose I have independent 2 ethereum blockchain on private net N1 and N2. A smart contract S exists on the blockchain N1. Consider that the smart contract S is self-complete and doesn't depend on any external state of the chain N1.

> Is it possible to download the smart contact from the chain N1 along with all the complete state of the contract S and deploy it in chain N2?

The deployed contract in chain N2 reflect the most recent state of the contract in N1 before the download.

> How to download a smart contract state (code and storage both) from a blockchain?